# Webservice for past weather data for JAPAN

Tags: json, web-services, api, weather

I want a web-service that provide weather information for japan.
somewhere i have found [this](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov), but here i can get data only for US.
[Reference](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices) i have found yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the web service on http://worldweatheronline.com/ but they are providing data to premium customer only and premium membership is free for 2 month after that you have to pay 5$ per month or 54$ per year.
Please let me know if u want code.